# Concurrently restarting multiple locked threads

Tags: concurrency, pthreads, mutex

I currently have N threads that are all open udp/tcp connections. When I receive the first packet out of any of the threads, the main thread  (that called the N threads) needs to pause execution in the N threads and do some work before resuming the N threads.

My initial idea was to have all N threads use a common mutex that waits on a pthread_cond_broadcast from the main thread. As I understand it, all N threads will resume execution in some sequential order as determined by the scheduler when broadcast is called, since they all depend on the same mutex. However, I need them to resume in parallel.

This is essentially what my problem looks like:

Main thread:

```
//create N threads. Each thread is connected to a different 
//location but uses the same code

//detect that one of the threads has received a packet
//tell all child threads to pause
pauseThreads();

//do some work on the first packet

resumeThreads();

//tell all child threads to resume
```

Child thread code:

```
while(true){
  recv() data


  //the other N-1 threads should ideally block here, 
  //since I'd like to process just the 
  //very first packet

  //hopefully pauseThreads() has been called by the main
  //thread by here if the first packet has been received.
  //All threads should block here until the main thread 
  //is done processing the first packet. Once it's done
  //processing, *firstPacket will be false and the if statement 
  //can be skipped over

  //only one thread should ever access this
  if(*firstPacket  /*this is a global variable*/  ){
      //process first packet
      *firstPacket = false;
      //the thread that receives the first packet should block here
  }

  //process same packet data in another format
}
```

The reason the threads need to restart concurrently is that speed is an issue and I can't wait for each thread to get through its own data processing one by one. I have the blocking within the if statement figured out, but I cannot think of a way to efficiently block the N-1 threads.

Comment: Why all the threads? If you are trying to synchronise them so tightly so that they behave as if there is one thread. Then consider using one thread.

Comment: Well, all the connections are run by the same entity. The data is broadcast across different channels but are all related to each other. If I do it all in one thread, I won't be able to keep up with the rate that data is coming in.

Comment: I don't understand the first 2 statements, but the 3rd about keeping up. To go as fast as possible: The upper limit on number of threads is one thread per processor core. The optimum is often lower. With the amount of locking you describe. I would suggest one thread no matter how many processor cores.

Comment: I just mean that if data could be labeled from A-Z - A-B is in one channel, B-C is in another, etc. All the data is from the same service but has to be spread out across different channels; ie the service runs multiple udp connections to broadcast all of its data. My program would be significantly less effective if the scheduler got to choose its own sequential order as I wouldn't be able to see the real-time relation between things received in different units. Essentially, things need to update based on data from the service, and latency would be a bad thing. (There are a lot of cores.)

Comment: Best get server to add timestamp or sequence number to udp packets. Alternatively, In the receiver, I assume you have exactly one net work adopter, and only one route between server and you, otherwise packets may get reordered. So now we need to time/sequence stamp packets, before further processing. Use a single thread for this. Summary. Get server to help, or use a processor-farm: first thread receives and timestamps, then farms out the rest of the task to worker threads.

Comment: I note you are doing the opposite of processor-farm. You have done to-many-managers: Lots of managers wait on a single resource (a network interface adaptor), and get a single worker to do all the work. Also if the managers go to sleep while the worker works. The order they so packet arrival, of packets that arrived while they where asleep, will not be related to the order they arrived, but to the order they wake up. (there will be an order to waking up, and there is nothing you can do to stop it. If you did you would just label all packets that arrived when sleeping with same time.)

Answer (score 0):

## Best

Get server to add timestamp or sequence number to udp packets.

## Alternatively

In the receiver, I assume you have exactly one net work adapter, and only one route between server and you. Otherwise packets may get reordered.

So now we need to time/sequence stamp packets, before further processing. Use a single thread for this, then farm out the rest of the task to worker threads.